# How to set temporary login path if home directory mount point (NFS mount) is not responding

Tags: unix, networking, nfs, nfsclient

All the users home directory in a server is remote NFS share mounted locally on mount point say : /home/workspace/username

At times due to network issue NFS share goes to non-responding state and if user try to login at this point SSH connection is closed with below error message:

- ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

I wanted to understand if there is any technical solution to find out if NFS share is not responding and if it is, users should be allowed to login to server but to a different ( temporary) home directory.

Basically i want to setup secondary(temporary) home directory option if primary home directory ( NFS share ) is not responding during users login.

Thanks in advance.